# format of a wait and delay function

Tags: sql, time, delay, wait, dts

What does `180 * 1` denote for, in a dts package that I'm looking at.

It's basically a dts package with SQL code.

The comments beside this says 120 minutes for `60*2` and 90 minutes for `180*1`.

Can some please help me understand this?

Comment: You forgot to show us the code you're asking about.

Comment: if ( datediff(ss,@lclstarttime,getdate()) > 180 * 1 ) ----loop SFTP for 90 mins to look for Complete.txt file

begin
  set @lclContinue = 0 
end

Answer (score 0):

The pasted code is a trigger that fires when it's 180 seconds (3 minutes) past the start time. If the comment is correct, it triggers a process that loops SFTP for 90 minutes. But you didn't paste any of the code that this triggers, whatever `lclContinue` does, so we can't tell how that comment relates to the code. If there is no such code and `lclContinue` directly causes the looping, then the comment is completely incorrect.

Comment: thanks David. This answers our question. So i assume, if its one hour of loop (for instance) it would be 60*60 or 180*20 etc.,.? whats up with the x * y concept. can't it just be the total number of seconds as just one number? like 3600.